# The Best Pettern to Use Entity Frame Work

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-4, content-management-system

I am going to start developing a web based application which will work like CMS. I intend to use Entity Frame Work to build my application's DAL.

I don't know what is the best pattern which I should use to build this kind of application. I also don't know about EF patterns which are considered as a best practices in world wide.

Please let me know where to start and what should be implemented to develop this application.

Comment: I would consider accepting some answers before asking more questions.

Comment: Too broad. Not suitable for Q&A. There is no conclusive answer to this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start with these:

[Basic Entity Framework Architecture Choices](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee236639.aspx)

[Example of the using Entity Framework in ASP.NET MVC](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/70061/Architecture-Guide-ASP-NET-MVC-Framework-N-tier-En)